# Concatenate timers in python

Tags: python, timer

I have this helper timer class:

```
class RepeatingTimer(object):
    def __init__(self, interval, f, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.interval = interval
        self.f = f
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.timer = None

    def callback(self):
        # The order is so self.f will be able to cancel the timer
        self.start()
        self.f(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

    def cancel(self, timer_id):
        self.timer.cancel()
        del timers[timer_id]

    def start(self):
        self.timer = Timer(self.interval, self.callback)
        self.timer.start()
```

What I want is to be able to execute a timer for example:

```
timers = {}
def execute_func(*args, **kwargs):
    print("hi")
timer_id = random.random()
timers[timer_id] = RepeatingTimer(1, execute_func)
timers[timer_id].start()
```

I need the code inside `execute_func` to be able to stop the timer, the thing is that I want to concatenate those timers execution, for example:

I execute the first timer(those 3 lines), each second the timer executes I run some code, at specified second I end the timer manually and want to execute another timer(those 3 lines).

I other words, when the first timer finish(manually, by some callback) I want to initiate a new timer, I've managed to achieve that with an ugly callbacks hierarchy way like:

```
main_cb("b1",
    lambda timer_id: main_cb("b2", 
        lambda timer_id: main_cb("b3")))
```

The problem is that I cannot iterate over `["b1", "b2", "b3"]` I have to do ugly nesting manually.

**In conclusion**: I'm looking for a way, general way to execute the same function with some parameters, one of those parameters should be a `done` callback, when called it will fire up the next iterator and so forth.

Comment: Side note: `def __init__(self, interval, f, *args, **kwargs):` would be much nicer and more sensible.

Comment: @AlexHall The original code did that I changed it but you'r right i'll probably should switch back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely iterate over that list to produce the nested callback:

```
from functools import partial

def main_cb(arg, next_cb=None):
    print(arg)
    if next_cb:
        next_cb()

callback = None
for b in reversed(['b1', 'b2', 'b3']):
    callback = partial(main_cb, b, callback)  # (lambda creates a late binding closure bug)

print(callback)
callback()
```

Output:

```
functools.partial(<function main_cb at 0x1007c0f28>, 'b1', functools.partial(<function main_cb at 0x1007c0f28>, 'b2', functools.partial(<function main_cb at 0x1007c0f28>, 'b3', None)))
b1
b2
b3
```